# Creating objects from a list which can vary in length

Tags: c#, class

I'm a beginner and trying to create a small app, which finds the best combination of license plans given customer requirements.

I've simplified the part I am having trouble with below. The plangroup is actually a class of other objects, so it is basically used to group different plans together (e.g. where they are compatible). So it's a nested class, but I haven't included that part for simplicity.

My issues are:

- I need to create planGroup objects based on the info in a list. The length of the list can vary.
- So the I have mutiple constructors so that objects can be created with different number of fields, is there a more concise way of doing that then writing a constructor for each possible number of arguments?
- How can I create the object from the list, without using multiple if statements to work out the length of the list?
- Once created, how can I get the values out of the object, given that I don't know how long it is, again without using multiple if statements?

Thanks and hope this makes sense!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
// easy to create an object when you know how many bits of info you have
            PlanGroup p1 = new PlanGroup("Plan 1 name", "Plan 2 name", 350);
            Console.WriteLine($"{p1.Plan1} / {p1.Plan2} / {p1.Cost}");

            // But what if we have a list of plan info that comes from another method, and could vary in length
            var planinfo = new List<string> { "Plan name", "Another plan name" };

            // could create the group object like this, but planinfo length will vary. The cost will be calculated and is not an issue.
            // but I don't want to do this as would have to use multiple if statements to based on planinfo count (in reality there might be up to 10).
            PlanGroup p2 = new PlanGroup(planinfo[0], planinfo[1], 200);

            // then also need a way of getting the details of the PlanGroup objects that is better than this, so will return all the plans as well as the cost
            Console.WriteLine($"{p2.Plan1} / {p2.Plan2} / {p2.Cost}");

        }

        class PlanGroup
        {
            public string Plan1 { get; set; } 
            public string Plan2 { get; set; }
            public string Plan3 { get; set; }
            public string Plan4 { get; set; }
            public int Cost { get; set; }

            public PlanGroup(string Plan1, string Plan2, int Cost)
            {
                this.Plan1 = Plan1;
                this.Plan2 = Plan2;
                this.Cost = Cost;
            }

            public PlanGroup(string Plan1, string Plan2, string Plan3, int Cost)
            {
                this.Plan1 = Plan1;
                this.Plan2 = Plan2;
                this.Plan3 = Plan3;
                this.Cost = Cost;
            }


            public PlanGroup(string Plan1, string Plan2, string Plan3, string Plan4, int Pages)
            {
                this.Plan1 = Plan1;
                this.Plan2 = Plan2;
                this.Plan3 = Plan3;
                this.Plan4 = Plan4;
                this.Cost = Cost;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second issue. You could use `System.Collections.Generic` to use a `List<T>`. In which you could just have a `List<string> Plans` in the class and have a similar constructor. I.E the constructor takes a `List<string>` as a parameter

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class PlanGroup {
        public List<string> Plans { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }

        public PlanGruop(int Cost, List<string> Plans) {
             this.Cost = Cost;
             this.Plans = Plans;
        }

    }
```

and the utilization of the constructor would look like

```
PlanGroup p = new PlanGroup(500, new List<string>{ "plan1", "plan2"... });
```

then to get the length (number of "plans" inside the list) You simply use `p.Plans.Count`. And accessing an element, is as easy as looking through an array `p.Plans[0]` and so on.

The question was a bit unclear, but i hope this gave you some answers.

Comment: The decision to use a collection property for `Plans` is correct, but it would probably be a better idea to use `params string[] plans` rather than a list. That way it would enable this syntax: `new PlanGroup(300, "Plan 1 name", "Plan 2 name");` as well as this: `new PlanGroup(300, planinfo.ToArray());`

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, rather than trying to store the contents of the list as fields in the class, I just store the whole list. I knew there must be a better way of doing this, this gives me something to go on so thank you!